# PMD Plugin is not showing in Juno(Eclipse IDE) after i installed it successfully

Tags: eclipse, pmd

I have successfully installed PMD in JUNO(Eclipse) but not able to see it in the properties.
I want to run the Project on PMD.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the confusion point is that for PMD you have to enable it first by clicking on properties of each project.

**select project-> Properties-> select PMD-> enable**

This is the gernaral issue many have faced this. you can check screen shot in below answer as well.

[After Installing PMD in Luna in Prespective it is Not Showing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29679945/after-installing-pmd-in-luna-in-prespective-it-is-not-showing)

Answer (score 0):

There are two PMD plug-ins for Eclipse: **PMD for Eclipse** and **eclipse-pmd**.

If you've installed the PMD plug-in using the Eclipse marketplace then you're using **eclipse-pmd** which requires Eclipse to run on a JVM version 7 or later. If you're running Eclipse on a JVM version 6 or earlier and you're using eclipse-pmd 0.7 or earlier [the PMD property page won't be visible](https://github.com/acanda/eclipse-pmd/issues/6).

To solve this problem you have to run Eclipse on a JVM version 7 or later. To change the JVM on which Eclipse runs you have to set the parameter `-vm` in your eclipse.ini accordingly. The Eclipse Wiki explains how to [specify the JVM](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM).

Comment: Hi,
I used --> http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/

i am using Juno on JDK 7.

Comment: In this case I unfortunately can't help you. You could try asking the question in the [PMD Help forum](http://sourceforge.net/p/pmd/discussion/188193/). Or install [eclipse-pmd](http://acanda.github.io/eclipse-pmd/) and see if this works for you.