# After Installing PMD in Luna in Prespective it is Not Showing?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin, pmd, eclipse-luna

I installed the **Pmd Plugin** in *Eclipse Luna* and in *STS*, in the installation history it is showing *installed* but it is not showing in the perspective, so I am not able to run my code through **PMD**.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Did you install eclipse-pmd 1.4 via the marketplace?

Answer (score 4):

If installed via the Market place, you then need to enable it for each Project...

[image: Project Properties]

Then select the ruleset you want to use.

The PROBLEMS view will then show the violations.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that you need to turn on PMD for each project separately. Which make sense, because you can have different rule set per project. So to turn it on, right click on **project -> “Preferences” -> “PMD”** (there would be two PMD sections if you didn’t uninstall old PMD plugin)-> “Enable PMD for this project” -> “Add…”. Now you should pick a location of PMD ruleset file.

These PMD warning sometimes clash with Eclipse native warnings, so there is possibility to make them more visible. Go to **“Window” -> “Preferences” -> “General” -> “Editors” -> “Text Editors” -> “Annotations”** and find “PMD Violations”.